# Overriding messages.properties in a springboot packaged jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

We have a springboot app packaged into a jar. While packaging, we bundled all config property files into the jar file except `application.properties` file.

Now, we do have a requirement to edit some keys inside a config file which is packaged in the jar. The file name is `messages.properties` which contains some error keys and values.

To override the `messages.properties` outside the jar, we did create a `message.properties` in `resources` folder and restarted the app, but app was still pointing to the `messages.properties` file bundled in the jar.

Now, my question is there a way we can override the `messages.properties` or the keys inside the `messages.properties` file without making any changes to the jar file?

I've tried my best to put the question in its best form, in case if you need more details please do let me know.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually whatever inside the jar should take the priority over the "non jar" properties like from any resources, environment properties, etc. If you think some key-values change often and you don't want to change the jar, it's better to keep those properties outside the jar.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach,

define a newmessage.properties with key overridden with values , put it in resource folder, in your **application.properties** add

```
spring.messages.basename = newmessage
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. hmm., in the jar file, we don't have an exclusive resources directory. Code and property files are bundled together leaving application.properties alone. Is is possible to create a directory close to application.properties file and give the relative or absolute path in application.properties file? If overriden, do we need to copy all the message keys in message.properties or just the needed keys?